# My introduction is not recognized

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

It seems that the sections that follow my table of contents are not recognized as sections separated from my toc: in the chapter called "Règles et conventions typographiques", instead, I can see "Sommaire détaillé". How could I fix that?
This is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire détaillé}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sommaire détaillé}
\clearpage
\chapter*{Règles et conventions typographiques}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Règles et conventions typographiques}
\end{document}
```

Comment: domi,  welcome back.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the output you get? I see what I expect to see. The `Sommaire détaillé` with two entries `Sommaire détaillé` and `Règles et conventions typographiques`. BTW: Instead of `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` you can use `\addchap` in the KOMA classes (which will always give you headers)

Comment: You should add the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so that the special characters show :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman That is not required with a LaTeX versions 2018-04-01 or above (or in earlier versions if Unicode engines such as XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX were used).

Comment: @moewe Seriously? Doesn't work for my pdflatex?

Comment: @moewe `pdflatex --version >>
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) ...`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Assuming you encoded the file in UTF-8 it should work if your LaTeX version is 2018-04-01 (you can check your version at the beginning of the `.log` file, mine is `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5`). See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Do not add a TOC entry for the TOC manually. In your MWE `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sommaire détaillé}` is executed on the last page of the TOC. So if your TOC takes two or more pages you will get a wrong page number in the TOC. KOMA-Script provides

```
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
```

to get a TOC entry for the TOC.

Then I would suggest to load `fontenc` with option `T1` and `babel` with option `french`. Then you can redefine `\contentsname` in the preamble using

```
\renewcaptionname{french}{\contentsname}{Sommaire détaillé}
```

Also other chapters should not be added manually to the TOC.  Use the KOMA-Script command `\addchap` for unnumbered chapters with entries in TOC and header. But in **`\frontmatter`** all chapters are unnumbered by default: So in your example you can simple use `\chapter` (without star!).

If you really need a unnumbered chapter without entries in TOC and head use `\addchap*`. This command cleans up the marks for the headers.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat,%
               french,% <- added
              ]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{babel}%<- added
\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}% no indent of first paragraph in a chapter, section etc.

\renewcaptionname{french}{\contentsname}{Sommaire détaillé}%<- change french \contentsname 

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOC entry for TOC

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Règles et conventions typographiques}% or \addchap{Règles et conventions typographiques}
Text
\clearpage
Text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you need a continuous arabic numbering for the document, then remove `\frontmatter\pagenumbering{arabic}` and do not use `\mainmatter`. To get unnumbered chapters use either `\addchap` or `\addchap*` (no entry in TOC and header).

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat,%
               french,% <- added
              ]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{babel}%<- added
\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}% no indent of first paragraph in a chapter, section etc.

\renewcaptionname{french}{\contentsname}{Sommaire détaillé}%<- change french \contentsname 

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOC entry for TOC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Règles et conventions typographiques}
Text
\clearpage
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. But the numbering is reset to zero from \mainmatter and I do need a continuous numbering.

Comment: Then remove `\frontmatter` , `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\mainmatter`. For the unnumbered chapters use `\addchap` or `\addchap*`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: It works perfectly!